# unable to move text up in react css component

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-hooks, css-selectors

I am trying to build out a component in React.

It kinda works. The only issue is that the text next to each boxicon is slightly below what I would want it to be. I've tried doing margin-bottom and padding-bottom to bring them up but it does not seem to be budging. Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should give the direct parent that wrap all these `span`s which is `AudioFileListElements` the `display: flex; flex-direction: row`, and to center all children vertically add `align-items: center`.

so the css for it will be:

```
.AudioFileListElements {
    background: #392F5A;
    height: 7%;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
```

and I said vertically, because with `flex-direction: row` the cross-axis will be the vertical, but with `flex-direction: column` it will horizontal.. [see reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)